# Format Text output in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I want to print several lines in front of the user using this code:

```
data.stream().forEach((dataObj) ->
                        {
                            tilePane.getChildren().add(new Text(dataObj.getOne() + "        " + dataObj.getSecond() + "        " + dataObj.getTh() + "     "
                                + dataObj.getLs() + "     " + dataObj.getLast()));
                        });
```

But as you can see the final result is not very formatted output:

[image]

Is there any way to format the columns?

Comment: Your pic suggests that the String that you are trying to fetch have whitespaces in them. Try to remove them !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options:

1. Easiest one is to use a monospace font where width of every symbol including space is the same, the most popular one is Courier New:

   ```
    text.setFont(Font.font ("Courier New", 14));
   ```
2. As you are providing the data in a tabular format you may opt to use `TableView` instead of `Text`
3. Finally, if you are really like this font and don't want to use `TableView` you can split your line in 4 `Text` instances and adjust each `Text` to be on the same coordinate as corresponding one from other lines. E.g.

   ```
   Text t1 = new Text(dataObj.getOne());
   t1.setMinWidth(100); // adjust according to real data
   Text t2 = new Text(dataObj.getSecond());
   t2.setMinWidth(100); // adjust according to real data
   Text t3 = new Text(dataObj.getTs());
   t3.setMinWidth(300); // adjust according to real data
   Text t4 = new Text(dataObj.getLs());
   t4.setMinWidth(300); // adjust according to real data
   Text t5 = new Text(dataObj.getLast());
   tilePane.getChildren().addAll(t1, t2, t3, t4, t5);
   ```

Comment: provided very simple way to achieve that